# IE eventDispatch() SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. ERROR

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I need to send data behind 2 separated windows via Custom Events.
I used Polifill from [MDN:CustomEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill) to create CustomEvent object.
So my code looks:

```
var chatwindow = window.open(chatRootURL + "chat_window.jsp", "chat", window_options, true);
var event = new CustomEvent("onmessagein", {
    detail: data,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
});
chatwindow.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Problem is I am getting error in IE9:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
```

in last line. Tested my code in Chrome and Firefox - works.

When I do :

```
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

event fires to current window object. But I want to fire it to another window.
Also I tried to fire normal Event (click) on separate window and got same error.

Is it possibly at all? Thanks.
If not, please suggest another how do it

Comment: Excuse me. In title is mistake - dispatchEvent() should be instead.

Comment: Please use the edit feature

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer is use jQuery for this.
This code found in network works very well:

```
href_window.$(href_window.document).trigger(customEvent);
```

but not with native javascript

Comment: The question is about vanilla JS and NOT jQuery.